# Flutter align textfield to bottom and text from top

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How do I align text from top and textfield from bottom? This is to create a sort of chat-like interface.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Hello, How are you?\nwow',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              //style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
              onChanged: (text) {
                //print("First text field: $text");
              },
              onSubmitted: (text) {
                print(text);
                //myController.clear();
                myController.text = "";
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText:"Enter your response."
              ),
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried separating the text and textfields into containers instead but to no avail.

Is there a way to do it in flutter similar to iOS layout constraints where textfield is constrained to keyboard height and text is constrained to textfield?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can insert an `Expanded` between the `Text` and `TextField` in your `Column`. This will take up as much space in between those as possible and thus push your `Text` up and `TextField` down:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text(...),
    Expanded(child: Container()),
    TextField(...),
  ],
);
```

Comment: wow that worked really well! Hmm mind if I ask if there's also a way to expand textview to the full size of body including padding? Right now it just seems to center. I've set text alignment to align left already

Comment: @Wilson You will need to remove all your alignments you have, just like the code in my answer. You aligned it to center with `CrossAxisAlignment.center`.

Comment: Hmm seems like I may have to create another container to house that. But now im not too sure how to expand the container to edges.

Comment: This works like a champ, but darn it seems kludgey. :-(